# Best way to set a bulk schedule?

Tags: dates, time

We are going to design an application wherein 2 persons can do a conference call to each other. One person is a consultant while the other is a customer.

The consultant needs to set his / her date & time of availability which the customer is able to book.

I can imagine it would be very tedious for the consultant to set the schedule one by one. Perhaps, the consultant would like to set his / her availability every Friday at 2PM-4PM.

However, the consultant should also be able to set an exception, e.g. that on a particular Friday, s/he is unavailable.

What is the best way to approach this and / or is there any existing application that has solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Considering I've understood your question well - I think showing consultant's calendar to customers would be appropriate with book button -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there are more conditions than what you have mentioned above. I would think of the following :

1- I agree with Diego - Calendar-based booking is very effective and allows the customer to choose the date and time in a convenient manner.
2- What if there are more than 1 or 10 customers, and the calendar looks full, how can the customer finds the available date and time to book ?

- In this case provide a filtering so that when the customer lands on the booking page and sees the calendar full , he/she can specify the date and time and filter the consultant's schedule.  This will reduce time and keeps the customer happy.
- Add priority and note option - depending on the objective  of your business , you can customize the booking-calendar.

3- Generate a link to the booking the customer made, in case of any changes in the schedule the customer could see it. I would suggest to ask the customer to submit his/her email address to keep them posted.

I  hope this would be useful.

Thank you